# how to fix Players.louie43pro.PlayerGui.admin.Frame.LocalScript:10: Expected identifier when parsing expression, got ')' error roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a problem in Roblox studio. There's an error when im trying to make an admin command script using local script.
The error is

> Players.louie43pro.PlayerGui.admin.Frame.LocalScript:10: Expected
> identifier when parsing expression, got ')'

I have tried so many things to fix this error.
please help.

This is the script that i have

```
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local commandEvent = rs:WaitForChild("CommandEvent")

local frame = script.Parent
local enter = frame.Enter
local box = frame.CommandBox
 
--takes command and splits it up
local function get_command()
    local command = ()
    for word in string.gmatch(box.Text, "\S+") do
        table.insert(command, word)
    end
    local action = command[1]
    local person = command[2]
    
    print(action)
    print(person)
    
    commandEvent:FireServer(action, person)
    
    box.Text = " "
end

enter.MouseButton1Click:Connect(get_command)
```

Can anybody help me with my problem?
please..

Comment: replace `local command = ()` with `local command = {}`  you need curly brackets to create a table, not parenthesis. you used the call operator where a table constructor is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`local command = ()`  is not valid Lua syntax.

`()` is the call operator. You want to create a table value so use the table constructor `{}`

`local command = {}`

Or maybe you forgot a function name? You could also do something like this

```
local command = getMeSomeTable()
```

Then the call operator would make sense. That function should return a table of course.

As soon as you have fixed this error you'll face another error for using an invalid escape sequence. Replace `\S` with `%S` to match a non-whitespace character.

In case you do not find 2 matches you'll run into the next error. So you should check if `command` actually has two elements at keys `1` and `2` befor you index them.

So maybe add something like

```
if action and person then command:FireServer(action, person) end
```